# facing issues with bitwise AND operation

Tags: sql, sqlite, blob, bitwise-and

I am using SQl database

I have one table having column datatype Blob.

```
for e.g:
create table Alarm(
id int,
xyz blob
);
```

this is my insert statements:

INSERT INTO Alarm values(2, '1000001');

INSERT INTO Alarm values(5, '0001000');

INSERT INTO Alarm values(7, '0110110');

this is my SELECT statement

SELECT * from Alarm where xyz & cast('1001001' as blob);

When I am using **Bitwise AND** operation it returns all records from table.
But in this scenario records 1 & 2 should be selected.

the **select** statement returns all records which is wrong.

please help me out.

Comment: I don't know whether you can do what you're trying with BLOBs, but... Are you remembering to mark `1001001` as a binary constant? As used above, it would be treated as 1,001,001 in decimal; the binary expansion of which _would_ match all records if doing a bit-wise AND.

Comment: select * from Alarm where Alarm.bt_str & cast(1001001 as Binary);   i have tried this but still its returns all records. please help me out

Comment: That `1001001` will still be being treated as a decimal number (one million, one thousand and one). Also, `B'0001000'` has no meaning in SQLite that I'm aware of, so please edit into your question examples of the actual  `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements you are using.

Comment: i have made the changes into my question. And  can i use Blob datatype for storing bit wise string so that i can perform bitwise AND operator into it?

Comment: Those are not blobs. Edit into your question examples of the actual INSERT and SELECT statements you are using.

Comment: 1. Please add your actual `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements; not just your data. 2. As I said, I suspect you can't do what you want with BLOBs, but people need to see your actual statements to be sure.

Comment: i have added actual INSERT and SELECT statements. And what should i use for storing binary strings so that i can use bit wise AND operator or is there any other way please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the actual statements. It confirms that what you want to do cannot be done that way, but see my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want, that is, store strings/BLOBs representing the binary value of a number and perform arithmetic or Boolean operations on them. SQLite has no built-in method for interpreting binary-digit-strings.

However, unless your binary-representations are longer than 64-bits, you can simply store the values as ordinary numbers, as the following transcript shows:

```
SQLite version 3.8.4.1 2014-03-11 15:27:36
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .read so.sql3

create table Alarm(
    id integer,
    xyz integer
);

insert into Alarm values
    ( 1, 65 ),     -- 0x41 == 00100001
    ( 2,  8 ),     -- 0x08 == 00001000
    ( 3, 54 )      -- 0x36 == 00110110
;

select * from Alarm where
    xyz & 73       -- 0x49 == 01001001
;
1|65
2|8
```

Obviously, if your "numbers" are arriving as binary-representations, or the results need to be delivered in such format, you will need to perform suitable conversions either side of the SQL statements. I believe a slightly later version of SQLite will accept the `0x41` notation to allow numbers to be specified in hexadecimal directly.

The only other option I can think of would be to define your own *User Defined Function* (see [Create Or Redefine SQL Functions](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) in the SQLite3 documentation), to perform *binary-string-to-integer* conversion. However, I've no experience of this, and unless there's a *very* compelling reason for storing the binary-representation as strings, it is probably overkill.